# System won't start

Tags: 11.10, boot, boot-failure

Ubuntu 11.10 will not start when I boot to it. When I boot it, it shows the loading screen display, but then goes straight to the shutdown screen and is stuck there. I have tried the recovery mode to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'd follow Mordoc's advice: Boot from a rescue system, mount /var/log and check the syslog out. Furthermore you should have a look at /boot - I have seen cases where this directory consumed 100 percent of the available partition space and therefore created the strangest errors.

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose, I would boot from live-cd or usb and mount the drive. From there, I would navigate to the /var/log/ dir and hunt through the syslog and kern logs.